# Vuejs call $refs

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

```
<div>
    <button @click="$refs.cart.open()">open</button>
    <drawer></drawer>
</div>
```

ref=cart is inside `<drawer>`, can I call from that button? how?

---edited---

[image]

> ---edited solve with vuex---

root template

```
toggle() {
    this.$store.dispatch('toggle', {
      toggle: 'close'
    }).then(() => {
      this.$store.dispatch('toggle', {
        toggle: 'open'
      })
    })
  }
```

inside drawer

```
computed: {
  toggle() {
    return this.$store.state.toggle
  }
},
watch: {
  toggle(val) {
    if (val == 'open') this.$refs.cart.open()
  }
}
```

Comment: A little more code will be helpful.

Comment: @saurabh ok edited, I use QuasarFramework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution (not the best) would be to just use a Vue event bus to communicate between components here. Quasar has a global event bus (http://quasar-framework.org/api/js-events.html).

Best solution would be to use Vuex but of course, not if you need it just for this.

Vue references are tricky and are not always ready to use. The explanation is long and has to do with how Vue renders.

Comment: I still don't understand to implement event bus on case above, please can u help open my mind with an example? Thx.